# How to calculate the sum of two adjacent row from one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following columns, the first column is index:

```
para
0  223.46
1   92.26
2   66.86
3   52.14
4   69.55
5   94.20
6  129.96
7  297.48
```

The sum will be the two adjacent row from one column
     new_index 0 will be the first value, 
     new_index1= old_index0+old_index1,
     new_index2=old_index1 + old_index2   ,......and so on.

so I guess I need a for loop here(or maybe not)

I tried several ways, really have no idea how to do it.
The follow is what I tried:

```
def sum(i):
for i in range (0,i):
    sum = data_10.icol[i] + data_10.icol[i+1]
return sum
```

I excepted to get:

```
para
0 223.46
1 315.72
2 159.12
3 119.00
4 121.69
5 163.75
6 224.16
7 427.38
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) `sum`

```
df.rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()
```

Comment: @graceli happy coding , :-)

Comment: How can I delete the new_index 0, because I think the first value is useless for the new dataframe.

Comment: `yourdf=df.rolling(2).sum().dropna()` @graceli